# Position different size circles around a circular path with no gaps

Tags: javascript, math, canvas

I'm creating a Canvas animation, and have managed to position x number of circles in a circular path. Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using:

```
var total = circles.length,
    i = 0,
    radius = 500,
    angle = 0,
    step = (2*Math.PI) / total;

for( i; i < total; i++ ) {
    var circle = circles[i].children[0],
        cRadius = circle[i].r,
        x = Math.round(winWidth/2 + radius * Math.cos( angle ) - cRadius),
        y = Math.round(winHeight/2 + radius * Math.sin( angle ) - cRadius);

    circle.x = x;
    circle.y = y;

    angle += step;
}
```

Which results in this:
[image]

What I am trying to achieve is for all the circles to be next to each other with no gap between them (except the first and last). The circles sizes (radius) are generated randomly and shouldn't adjust to fit the circular path:

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

I expect there to be a gap between the first and last circle.

I'm struggling to get my head around this so any help would be much appreciated :)

Cheers!

Comment: Oeh, math. Fun. Does every `step` have to be equal? That makes it easy.

Comment: Hmm... I think that's a clue... :)

Comment: And btw you've a typo here: var total = cirlces.length

Comment: Corrected. Thanks matthias_h

Comment: I'm still struggling here Rudie. Can you elaborate please :)

Comment: Lol, thanks mate. I'm doing the same here!

Comment: I'm not getting very far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's something like this, but you're gonna have to figure out the last circle's size:

http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/ufvf62yf/2/

The main logic:

```
var firstStep = 0, rad = 0, step = 0;
firstStep = step = stepSize();
for ( var i=0; i<30; i++ ) {
    draw.radCircle(rad, step);
    rad += step;
    step = stepSize();
    rad += step;
}
```

- `stepSize()` creates a random rad between `Math.PI/48` and `Math.PI/48 + Math.PI/36` (no special reason, but it looked good). You can fix that to be the right sizes.
- `draw.radCircle(rad, step)` creates a circle at position `rad` of size `step` (also in rad).
- `step` is added twice per iteration: once to step from current circle's center to its edge and once to find the next circle's center
- `firstStep` is important because you have to know where to stop drawing (because the first circle crosses into negative angle)
- I haven't figured out how to make the last circle the perfect size yet =)

There's also a bit of magic in `draw.radCircle()`:

```
var r = rRad * Math.PI/3 * 200 * .95;
```

- The `200` is obviously the big circle's radius
- The `95%` is because the circle's edge length is slightly longer than the (straight) radius of every circle
- I have no idea why `Math.PI/3` is that... I figured it had to be Math.PI/2, which is 1 rad, but that didn't work at all. `1/3` for some reason does..... Explain that!

If you want to animate these circle sizes and keep them aligned, you'll have a hard time. They're all random now. In an animation, only the very first iteration can be random, and the rest is a big mess of cache and math =)

Answer (score 3):

Main creation loop :
• take a current radius
• compute the angles it cover   ( = atan2(smallRadius/bigRadius)  )
• move base angle by this latest angle.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/dj2v7mbw/9/

```
function CircledCircle(x, y, radius, margin, subCircleCount, subRadiusMin, subRadiusMax) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.subCircleCount = subCircleCount;
    var circles = this.circles = [];
    // build top sub-circles
    var halfCount = Math.floor(subCircleCount / 2);
    var totalAngle = addCircles(halfCount);
    // re-center top circles
    var correction = totalAngle / 2 + Math.PI / 2;
    for (var i = 0; i < halfCount; i++) this.circles[i].angle -= correction;
    // build bottom sub-circles
    totalAngle = addCircles(subCircleCount - halfCount);
    // re-center bottom circles
    var correction = totalAngle / 2 - Math.PI / 2;
    for (var i = halfCount; i < subCircleCount; i++) this.circles[i].angle -= correction;
    // -- draw this C
    this.draw = function (angleShift) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.circles.length; i++) drawDistantCircle(this.circles[i], angleShift);
    }
    //
    function drawDistantCircle(c, angleShift) {
        angleShift = angleShift || 0;
        var thisX = x + radius * Math.cos(c.angle + angleShift);
        var thisY = y + radius * Math.sin(c.angle + angleShift);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(thisX, thisY, c.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + (c.index * 15) + ',75%, 75%)';
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    //
    function addCircles(cnt) {
        var currAngle = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
            var thisRadius = getRandomInt(subRadiusMin, subRadiusMax);
            var thisAngle = Math.atan2(2 * thisRadius + margin, radius);
            var thisCircle = new subCircle(thisRadius, currAngle + thisAngle / 2, i);
            currAngle += thisAngle;
            circles.push(thisCircle);
        }
        return currAngle;
    }
}
```

with

```
function subCircle(radius, angle, index) {
    this.r = radius;
    this.angle = angle;
    this.index = index;
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

use with

```
 var myCircles = new CircledCircle(winWidth / 2, winHeight / 2, 350, 2, 24, 5, 50);
 myCircles.draw();
```

animate with :

```
var angleShift = 0;

function draw() {
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, winWidth, winHeight);
    myCircles.draw(angleShift);
    angleShift += 0.010;
}
draw();
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This looks great! However, the circleCount directly effects the size of the circles. I have all my circle sizes defined already and want them to stay the same size. Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: You have it animated here : http://jsfiddle.net/dj2v7mbw/6/  :-) You mean you want to 'fill' the circle's circumference with all your circles that have a fixed size, then leave the rest of the circle empty ?

Comment: Correct. I'm actually going to have half the circles along the top and the other half along the bottom of the circle, with spaces left and right :)

Comment: Could you update your post with, say, a function that provides an array filled with the desired radius ? i'll see how to update my answer.

Comment: The radius for each circle are actually generated randomly between 5 and 50 pixels using a simple function cRadius = getRandomInt(5, 50); I'll add this into the question though...

Comment: Thanks so much! You're a star! 10 beers on me!

Comment: then you might accept my answer. I'll drink them one by one on the next 10 days, thanks ! ;-)